# How to invoke the super user request prompt from the commandline

Tags: java, android, adb, root, su

I want to invoke the super user request prompt from the command line but could not do it.
Here's the code

```
am start -a com.topjohnwu.magisk.request -n com.topjohnwu.magisk/.request.RequestActivity
```

Its giving the error as follows

```
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.topjohnwu.magisk/com.topjohnwu.magisk.request.RequestActivity} does not exist.
```

Please help me.
Any help is apperiatated & thanks in advance.

I wanted to invoke the super user request prompt from the command line but could not do it.

And got the error as follows

```
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.topjohnwu.magisk/com.topjohnwu.magisk.request.RequestActivity} does not exist.
```

Comment: Why do you want to invoke that activity? usually you simply execute `su` and the request prompt for adb shell is displayed.

Comment: Yes, I do want to invole that activity & moreover I want to explicitly call the prompt so that if permission denied by mistake then again it can be granted using the prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Try just using
'su'
I hope it helps

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).